# Can not edit SQL instance

Tags: sql, edit, google-cloud-sql, disabled-control

Recently migrated to Google Cloud SQL.

Was working fine, but now I have lost the ability to manage authorized networks or edit the instance. I still have an option to delete though...

Any ideas on how I can edit this instance and regain access to my data?

Its not an access control problem (or I would not have delete option).

[Edit SQL instance option greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P4FI.png)

Comment: Is this a Second Generation instance? Can you do a hard refresh of your browser?

Comment: Second Generation. I refreshed, signed out and in many times, emptied cache, even tried another computer. It finally was possible to edit again after about 3 hours. Still no idea what happened. Unfortunately, I no longer trust Google SQL 2nd Gen for production use. I see no reason why the ability to edit authorised networks, restart, restore etc should be disabled without a good reason.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. If you send an e-mail to cloud-sql@google.com with your instance details we can take a look to identify what went wrong and make sure it doesn't happen again. Even if you're not planning to use Cloud SQL, I'd still like to make sure we can identify what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for unlocking, however, same thing happened again. This time when exporting. Export failed with an "Unknown error" now the database can not be edited and it permanently says "Exporting data..." even after a refresh.