# Cannot edit Google Cloud SQL Instance, getting a blank screen

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to edit the Google Cloud SQL instance but when I click on the Edit button on the top all I see is a blank screen (it tries to load but shows a blank screen). I need to change the Tier from D4 to D8 since I am getting database transaction time outs.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this issue so that I can make the configuration changes.

I am using the first generation instance.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? When you get the blank screen, does a hard refresh help (Ctrl + F5 if using Chrome)? Does it work in an Incognito/Private browsing window?

Comment: I have tried safari, IE , Chrome... tried multiple OS's all have the same blank page. Strangely I have 2 instances of Google cloud SQL, on one I can open the Edit screen and see all the configurations but the other just provides a blank page.

Comment: There is one other user who is having the same trouble : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402712/can-not-edit-sql-instance . So looks like this is system wide. Could anyone at Google help me with this system issue without having to spend $450 on support costs.

Comment: I also sent an e-mail to cloud-sql@google.com providing details of my account along with the instance details. I just received an e-mail asking me to sign up for Gold support ($450) to get an answer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you have "two instances"? Do you see two items in the instance list instead of one as you expect? A screenshot would be helpful. The other issue you linked to was tracked down to a problem specific to Second Generation instances. I'm an engineer on the Cloud SQL team and I'm trying to help :)

Comment: As expected I do see 2 instances. Once instance is a production instance and the other is a test instance. The test instance I am able to go to the Edit screen and make configuration changes but on the production instance I only see a blank page for the Edit screen. I can send you more details including screenshots but not sure if stack overflow is a good place for it?

Comment: I have now attached a screenshot of the blank page I am seeing.

Comment: Vadim, I am glad that I am working directly with you. Is it possible for you to upgrade my instance from d4 to d8 since I am having a major production issue(sql timeouts due to lack of enough memory).

Comment: Vadim, Thanks for your quick response. I just responded back to your e-mail, could you please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

We have identified a problem affecting some subset of instances that may cause them to become uneditable in Developer Console. 
It is more likely to affect older instances that do not have a "Preferred location" set.

It is still possible to modify the instance by using the Cloud SQL API (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/)

We are working on a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The great guys at Google helped me resolve this issue quickly. It was an internal system issue and they offered me a workaround within a few hours.

Comment: Can you share more about the workaround?